T/F: If $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{>1}$ is not Pisot, then $\{\lfloor\alpha^n\rfloor:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ contains infinitely many odd and even integers
True or false:

If $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{>1}\setminus\mathbb{N},$ then
the set $\{ \lfloor \alpha^n \rfloor: n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ contains
infinitely many even integers and infinitely many odd integers?

This is False for some Pisot numbers, e.g. $\alpha = 2+\sqrt{3}.$ We can see this by recalling the trick where you look at $(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ or $(2+\sqrt{3})^n - (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ (I can't remember which one), and then let $n\to\infty.$

But what about for $1)$ rational numbers, $2)$ non-Pisot algebraic
numbers, and $3)$ non-algebraic (i.e. transcendental ) numbers?


"For every non-Pisot number $\alpha$, $\lfloor\alpha^n\rfloor$ contains infinitely many even/odd numbers" is false. I don't know about if there are infinitely many algebraic counterexamples.
For every infinite binary string $c_1c_2c_3c_4\ldots$ ($c_i\in\{0,1\}$), I claim that there is some $\alpha>1$ such that $\lfloor\alpha^n\rfloor\equiv c_n\pmod 2$ for all $n$. The construction will be by nested closed intervals.
Define $I_1=[c_1+100,c_1+100.5]$, so $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor\equiv c_1\pmod2$ for $\alpha\in I_1$. Assuming $I_n$ has been defined, define $I_{n+1}$ to be some closed subinterval of $I_n$, such that for every $\alpha\in I_{n+1}$, $\lfloor\alpha^{n+1}\rfloor$ has the same parity as $c_{n+1}$, and such that $\{x^{n+1}\mid x\in I_{n+1}\}$ has length at least $0.5$. We check that this is well-defined as follows: let $I_n=[a,\sqrt[n]{a^n+0.5}]$. Then $\{x^{n+1}\mid x\in I_n\}=[a^{n+1},(a^n+0.5)^{(n+1)/n}]$, and
$$(a^n+0.5)^{(n+1)/n}=a^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1{2a^n}\right)^{(n+1)/n}>a^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac1{2a^n}\right)>a^{n+1}+\frac a2\ge a^{n+1}+50$$
where the first inequality is by Bernoulli and the second by $I_n\subseteq I_1$. So, $\{x^{n+1}\mid x\in I_n\}$ contains some closed interval $J_{n+1}$ such that every element of $J_{n+1}$ has integer part of the same parity as $c_{n+1}$, and $J_{n+1}$ has length at least $0.5$. We can now let $I_{n+1}=\{x^{1/(n+1)}\mid x\in J_{n+1}\}$.
$\{I_n\}$ is a sequence of nested closed intervals, so their intersection is nonempty. An element $\alpha$ of their intersection will have the desired property. So there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ many $\alpha>1$ such that $\lfloor\alpha^n\rfloor$ contains infinitely many even/odd numbers, and $2^{\aleph_0}$ many of them will be transcendental (therefore non-Pisot).
